# How does Flutter render desktop apps on Linux?

Tags: linux, flutter, dart, rendering, flutter-linux

I'm curious about the underlying rendering process of Flutter desktop apps on Linux. As I understand, Flutter uses Skia for graphics rendering, but how does it interact with the Linux operating system to display the UI elements on the screen? Are there any specific APIs or libraries used for this process? Additionally, how does Flutter handle performance and resource utilization when rendering complex UI elements in desktop applications? Any insights or resources on this topic would be greatly appreciated.

I tried to find any document, but I did not find it.

Comment: Are you asking how Skia draws to the screen on Linux?

Comment: Yes and how GTK is involve in this process.